# Gitlab Ci - Job can run successful without executing all script commands. How to execute multiple docker commands in the script?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I am using GitLab CI/CD with Docker to create Docker images, in this case to create a image of my application and publish it to a container registry.

The problem: Gitlab ci tells me the job succeeded but only 1 command was executed "**docker build** ..." and the **command "docker push ..." was not executed**.

```
build:
  variables:
    <<: *app-variables
  stage: build and push image
  before_script:
    - docker login $DOCKER_REGISTRY -u $DOCKER_AUTH_USER -p $DOCKER_AUTH_PASSW
    - cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR/apps/$DOCKER_APP_FOLDER
  script:
    - |
      docker build --target=buildimage -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$DOCKER_REPO/$DOCKER_APP_FOLDER/build:$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH .
      docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$DOCKER_REPO/$DOCKER_APP_FOLDER/build:$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```

I already tried to change script command to the bellow code but has the same behaviour.

```
script:
    - docker build --target=buildimage -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$DOCKER_REPO/$DOCKER_APP_FOLDER/build:$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH .
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$DOCKER_REPO/$DOCKER_APP_FOLDER/build:$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```

Note:
I don't know if it is related but the build of the image can take some time ~30min.

I followed the documentation on [Gitlab Docker Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html)

[image: Script result]

Comment: after_script also producing same result ?

Comment: @antoniomerlin is not possible because we don't have access to changes done by scripts defined in before_script or script.
Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#after_script